# How to select a Java Code signing Certificate Authority?

Tags: java, java-web-start, digital-signature, digital-certificate, code-signing-certificate

I am having one Java web start application which is self signed which shows security warning that a trusted certificate is missing each time it is accessed by the users.

Following is the details of my Java web start application.

1. Application uses Java web-start technology which communicates with the Servlets running on Tomcat7.
2. DB is SQL Server 2012.
3. Server Machine: Windows 64 bit 2008 R2 Enterprise Server.
4. Java 7 update 25 64 bit
5. All the files(JNLP, jarfiles) needed for the JWS-app and the Web-app is packed as a single war file and deployed to Tomcat7.

So I am planning to get a digital certificate for it. I found the prices listed in the below mentioned URL:
https://www.thesslstore.com/products/code-signing-certificates.aspx
There is a huge difference in price between the high price compared to the low price. So I am confused which I should prefer because I am unaware of the difference in certificating authorities.

If I can get an idea about the pros and cons of certificate / certificating authorities then I might be able to choose the best one for me.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Be aware that "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." Its not that these are bad questions, just that they've been found not to work well in the Q&A format

Comment: Whatever you do, try to pick a CA that is supported by the latest JVM truststore.

Comment: In my experience, going with the cheaper ones is more likely to result in false certificate errors than the pricier options.  The expensive roots seem to be embedded in a lot more software.  The cheap ones, not so much, which means more end users that get scary messages that they shouldn't be receiving.